# Extract icon name from *.icl, *.dll

Tags: winapi, icons

An icon library is file containing one or more icons and their names.
To extract icon we use ExtractIcon function.
What function to use to extract icon name?

Comment: Icons don't have "names". What problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: Some ICL has names. But its non-standard resource block.

Comment: In Visual Studio, use File + Open + File and select the .icl file.  High odds that you'll only see numbers, not names.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the resource ID/name then you will need to enumerate them using the standard resource enumeration functions (`EnumResourceTypes`, `EnumResourceNames`, `EnumResourceLanguages`).